# Return the records of one table with the relation of another in array format

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get the data of a table and its relationship with another by using the following form:

I have 3 tables

```
-Contry
-Province
-Entity
```

A Country can have several provinces and a Province can have several entities. 
I already have the models and relationships defined and they work, what I have not achieved is the following:
I want to obtain a multidimensional array with the following structure:

```
-Country1
   -Province1
      Entity1
      Entity2
      Entity3
-Country2
   -Province1
      Entity1
      Entity2
```

What have I tried:

```
$entities = Country::with(['provinces' => function($province) {
   return $province->with('entities');
}])->get()->toArray();
```

but this returns me an arrangement as follows:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:7 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Country1"
    "abbreviation" => "CT1"
    "active" => true
    "created_at" => "2020-02-27 17:27:57"
    "updated_at" => "2020-02-27 17:27:57"
    "provinces" => array:16 [▶]
  ]
  1 => array:7 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "Country2"
    "abbreviation" => "CT2"
    "active" => true
    "created_at" => "2020-02-27 17:27:57"
    "updated_at" => "2020-02-27 17:27:57"
    "provinces" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:7 [▼
        "id" => 17
        "name" => "Province1"
        "country_id" => 2
        "active" => true
        "created_at" => "2020-02-27 17:27:57"
        "updated_at" => "2020-02-27 17:27:57"
        "entities" => array:2 [▶]
      ]
      1 => array:7 [▼
        "id" => 18
        "name" => "Province2"
        "country_id" => 2
        "active" => true
        "created_at" => "2020-02-27 17:27:57"
        "updated_at" => "2020-02-27 17:27:57"
        "entities" => []
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

As you can see, the value of entities is empty, could you help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$entities = Country::with(['provinces.entities'])->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: Yes, sorry it was just to look cleaner, I don't see what the problem here, the value Province1 entities is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for those who come here in search of an answer, they managed to solve the problem in the following way:

```
$entities = Country::with(['provinces' => function($province) {
            return $province->has('entities');
        }])->get()->transform(function($country) {
            return [$country->name => $country->provinces->transform(function($province) {
                return [$province->name => $province->entities->pluck('name', 'id')];
            })->collapse()];
        })->collapse()->toArray();
```

Basically what it does is obtain all the countries and all the provinces that contain at least 1 entity.